# VSCode debugging NodeJs project in TypeScript with modules - SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Tags: node.js, typescript, vscode-debugger

I am having an issue with VSCode to start debugging a NodeJs project in Typescript with modules in a standard test boilerplate project.

I am running in a vicious circle of 2 VSCode errors:

```
SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

and after adding entry to file:  **package.json**

```
"type": "module",
```

I get error:

```
Uncaught TypeError TypeError [ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION]: Unknown file extension ".ts" for C:\data\projects\project-a01\src\main.ts
```

In terminal, the app runs fine !
So the issue is with VSCode or I am missing something in my **launch.json** file.

Here are the steps I am taking to create the project:

OS: Windows 11

Global installs:

```
    +-- node 19.2.0
    +-- npm 8.19.3
    +-- @jessety/pm2-logrotate@2.7.1
    +-- @nestjs/cli@9.1.8
    +-- @types/node@18.11.18
    +-- @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@5.48.0
    +-- @typescript-eslint/parser@5.48.0
    +-- eslint@8.31.0
    +-- node-windows@1.0.0-beta.6
    +-- pm2@5.2.2
    +-- rimraf@3.0.2
    +-- ts-node@10.9.1
    `-- typescript@4.9.4
```

Project creation commands:

```
    mkdir C:\data\projects\project-a01
    cd    C:\data\projects\project-a01
    mkdir .vscode
    mkdir src
    mkdir src\functions
    npm init -y
    npm install typescript --save-dev
    npm install ts-node --save-dev
    npm install @types/node --save-dev
    npx tsc --init --outDir dist
    npm init @eslint/config
```

This quickly, beautifully creates a NodeJs, TypeScript project with the following - slightly edited:

**package.json:**

```
{
  "name": "project-a01",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "npx rimraf dist && tsc",
    "start": "npm run build && node dist/main.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^18.11.18",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.48.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.48.0",
    "eslint": "^8.31.0",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "typescript": "^4.9.4"
  }
}
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
    {
      "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es2016",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "outDir": "dist",
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "strict": true,
        "skipLibCheck": true
      }
    }
```

**src/main.ts**

```
import { test } from "./functions/test.function";

function launchApp() {
  console.log('Hello');
  test();
}
launchApp();
```

**src\functions\test.function.ts**

```
export function test() {
  console.log('Hello2');
}
```

Commands to compile and run:

```
tsc
node dist/main.js
```

and we get:

```
Hello
Hello2
```

All works fine !

NOW to VSCode - file:  **.vscode\launch.json**

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "VSC-debug",
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "skipFiles": [
        "<node_internals>/**"
      ],
      "program": "${workspaceFolder}/src/main.ts",
      "outFiles": [
        "${workspaceFolder}/dist/**/*.js"
      ],
      "sourceMaps": true
    }
  ]
}
```

. . .  and when trying to launch in VSCode one of the 2 errors pops up - depending on the condition of adding/removing  "type": "module" from package.json as described at the beginning.

The question is: How to fix these errors and get VSCode to run this basic project in debug mode and allow debugging with code breaks ?

Answer (score 3):

So after more research, here are the steps that made VSCode start working on the TypeScript project.

**tsconfig.json**  - add:

```
"rootDir": "./src",
"moduleResolution": "node",
"sourceMap": true,
```

**.vscode\launch.json**

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "VSC-debug",
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "program": "${workspaceFolder}\\src\\main.ts",
      "preLaunchTask": "npm: build",
      "sourceMaps": true,
      "smartStep": true,
      "internalConsoleOptions": "openOnSessionStart",
      "outFiles": [
          "${workspaceFolder}/dist/**/*.js"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

For those interested, the steps in the above question and the adjustment in this answer will give us a nice and simple:
***NodeJs - TypeScript project boilerplate / template*** - workable in VSCode.